# IBM Watson Assistant: How to get list of intents by API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Please is there any API to get a list of intents for an assistant like it exist for Logs :
GET /v2/assistants/{assistant_id}/logs

I used this URL but it dosen't work:
GET /v2/assistants/{assistant_id}/intents

Answer (score 1):

The [V1 API of IBM Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1) provides access to intents, entities and more. See the "[List Intents](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1#listintents)" API function for what you want to achieve.

The docs have sample code for various programming languages, but the intent data could be retrieved using **curl**, too:

```
curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" "{url}/v1/workspaces/{workspace_id}/intents?version=2021-06-14"
```

This is in the V2 API docs:

> To see the service credentials and the workspace ID of a workspace, go to the Skills page and select View API Details from the menu of a skill tile. (The workspace ID is used only by the v1 API.)

Comment: I'm using cloud pack for data i have only the assistantId with Bearer Token information to connect to assistant

Comment: Well, that information was not part of your question.  Did you read here about authentication? Bearer tokens are supported. https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1#authentication

Comment: Authentication with bearer token it works for the version V2, but in v1 we must specify the workspace_id (in cloud pack for data we do not have workspace_id only simple URL to connect  and assistant_id)

Comment: I added a sentence regarding the workspace ID. Even your environment should have it